# Choose a specific variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to use a function inside a loop and here is my code:

```
 for (var i =a ; i < a+s; i++){
   this.mat[i].color.setHex(0xffffff)
   this.mat[b].color.setHex(0xffffff)


    this.domEvents.addEventListener(this.cases[i], 'click', function(event){

      this.tween = new TWEEN.Tween(pions.position)
                    .to({ x: cases[i].position.x, y: cases[i].position.y, z: 5}, 10000)
                    .start();

  }, false)
     this.domEvents.addEventListener(this.cases[b], 'click', function(event){

        this.tween = new TWEEN.Tween(pions.position)
                     .to({ x: cases[b].position.x, y: cases[b].position.y, z: 5}, 10000)
                     .start();
  }, false)

     b--  
  }
```

My problem is that in the function of the `addEventListener` in `case[i].position`. I want to use the `i` from the `this.cases[**i**]`, not the `i` from the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a function instead to attach the event like :

```
for (var i = a; i < a + s; i++) {
  this.mat[i].color.setHex(0xffffff)
  this.mat[b].color.setHex(0xffffff)

  attachEvent(this, i);
  attachEvent(this, b);

  b--;
}

function attachEvent(_this, index) {
  _this.domEvents.addEventListener(_this.cases[index], 'click', function(event) {

    _this.tween = new TWEEN.Tween(pions.position)
      .to({
        x: cases[index].position.x,
        y: cases[index].position.y,
        z: 5
      }, 10000)
      .start();
  }, false)
}
```

Comment: have a error :  [Show/hide message details.] ReferenceError: attachEvent is not defined[Learn More]  who can call a function in a class

Comment: Try to declare the function before the loop

Comment: it's work thank a lot

Comment: Glad I could help brother